# What is hierarchy among crd such as clusteroperators,clusterversionoperator in openshift 4

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Currently there are more than **70 CRD**s (Custom Resources Definition) in newly created **openshift 4 cluster**.

```
[suvi@toolbox ~]# oc get crd --no-headers | wc -l
77
```

```
[suvi@toolbox ~]# oc get crd
clusterautoscalers.autoscaling.openshift.io                 2019-10-22T14:20:18Z
clusterloggings.logging.openshift.io                        2019-10-23T14:20:01Z
clusternetworks.network.openshift.io                        2019-10-22T14:20:50Z
clusteroperators.config.openshift.io                        2019-10-22T14:19:53Z
clusterresourcequotas.quota.openshift.io                    2019-10-22T14:19:54Z
clusterserviceversions.operators.coreos.com                 2019-10-22T14:20:23Z
clusterversions.config.openshift.io                         2019-10-22T14:19:53Z
configs.imageregistry.operator.openshift.io                 2019-10-22T14:20:16Z
configs.samples.operator.openshift.io                       2019-10-22T14:20:16Z
consoleclidownloads.console.openshift.io                    2019-10-22T14:20:16Z
consoleexternalloglinks.console.openshift.io                2019-10-22T14:20:20Z
consolelinks.console.openshift.io                           2019-10-22T14:20:18Z
consolenotifications.console.openshift.io                   2019-10-22T14:20:21Z
consoles.config.openshift.io                                2019-10-22T14:19:55Z
consoles.operator.openshift.io                              2019-10-22T14:20:22Z
containerruntimeconfigs.machineconfiguration.openshift.io   2019-10-22T14:22:32Z
controllerconfigs.machineconfiguration.openshift.io         2019-10-22T14:22:29Z
credentialsrequests.cloudcredential.openshift.io            2019-10-22T14:20:18Z
dnses.config.openshift.io                                   2019-10-22T14:19:55Z
dnses.operator.openshift.io                                 2019-10-22T14:20:17Z
dnsrecords.ingress.operator.openshift.io                    2019-10-22T14:20:18Z
egressnetworkpolicies.network.openshift.io                  2019-10-22T14:20:51Z
elasticsearches.logging.openshift.io                        2019-10-23T14:20:45Z
featuregates.config.openshift.io                            2019-10-22T14:19:56Z
hostsubnets.network.openshift.io                            2019-10-22T14:20:50Z
imagecontentsourcepolicies.operator.openshift.io            2019-10-22T14:19:56Z
images.config.openshift.io                                  2019-10-22T14:19:56Z
infrastructures.config.openshift.io                         2019-10-22T14:19:56Z
ingresscontrollers.operator.openshift.io                    2019-10-22T14:20:20Z
ingresses.config.openshift.io                               2019-10-22T14:19:56Z
installplans.operators.coreos.com                           2019-10-22T14:20:23Z
kubeapiservers.operator.openshift.io                        2019-10-22T14:20:17Z
kubecontrollermanagers.operator.openshift.io                2019-10-22T14:20:17Z
kubeletconfigs.machineconfiguration.openshift.io            2019-10-22T14:22:31Z
kubeschedulers.operator.openshift.io                        2019-10-22T14:20:16Z
machineautoscalers.autoscaling.openshift.io                 2019-10-22T14:20:20Z
machineconfigpools.machineconfiguration.openshift.io        2019-10-22T14:22:30Z
machineconfigs.machineconfiguration.openshift.io            2019-10-22T14:22:28Z
machinedisruptionbudgets.healthchecking.openshift.io        2019-10-22T14:21:03Z
machinehealthchecks.healthchecking.openshift.io             2019-10-22T14:21:02Z
machines.machine.openshift.io                               2019-10-22T14:21:02Z
machinesets.machine.openshift.io                            2019-10-22T14:21:02Z
mcoconfigs.machineconfiguration.openshift.io                2019-10-22T14:20:21Z
netnamespaces.network.openshift.io                          2019-10-22T14:20:50Z
network-attachment-definitions.k8s.cni.cncf.io              2019-10-22T14:20:45Z
networks.config.openshift.io                                2019-10-22T14:19:57Z
networks.operator.openshift.io                              2019-10-22T14:19:58Z
oauths.config.openshift.io                                  2019-10-22T14:19:57Z
openshiftapiservers.operator.openshift.io                   2019-10-22T14:20:18Z
openshiftcontrollermanagers.operator.openshift.io           2019-10-22T14:20:19Z
operatorgroups.operators.coreos.com                         2019-10-22T14:20:25Z
operatorhubs.config.openshift.io                            2019-10-22T14:19:54Z
operatorsources.operators.coreos.com                        2019-10-22T14:20:19Z
```

specifically, for clusterversion, clusteroperators?

Is there a way to get hierarchical view of these resources  as `deployment-> repilcaset->pod`?